# C++ - Ningún operador "+" coincide con estos comandos

Tags: sql, c++, conversión-de-tipos

Buenos días estoy realizando una aplicación de C++ que inserta datos de productos en una BD de SQL Server y estoy teniendo problemas para meter las variables de nombre, descripción, stock y precio en la cadena de SQL... me arroja el siguiente error por más que realizo la conversión de string a wstring:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estuve viendo diversos métodos para realizar la conversión a wstring pero ninguno me ha funcionado hasta el momento, que estoy haciendo mal?

Aquí está el código, las variables las declaré más arriba en el método en la que primero insto al usuario que introduzca datos en los campos de nombre, descripción etc y luego hago la conversión a string de las dos primeras.

```
cout << "Desea introducir el producto en la base de datos? (s/n)" << endl;
            cin >> resp;

            //Hacemos la conversión a wstring de las variables
            wnombre = wstring(nombre.begin(), nombre.end());
            wdescripcion = wstring(descripcion.begin(), descripcion.end());

            if (resp == 's') {
                //Defino la cadena de conexión con la BD
                SQLWCHAR* cadenaInsert = (SQLWCHAR*) L"INSERT INTO Productos (nombre, descripcion, stock, precio) VALUES ('" + wnombre + "', '" + wdescripcion + "', '" + to_wstring(stock) + "', '" + to_wstring(precio) + "')";
                wcout << "Ejecutando: " << cadenaInsert << endl;
                //Libero cualquier resultado pendiente de la BD para ejecutar las siguientes instrucciones
                retcode = SQLFreeStmt(sqlstatementhandle, SQL_CLOSE);
                //Preparo la cadena SQL para su ejecución
                retcode = SQLPrepare(sqlstatementhandle, cadenaInsert, sizeof(cadenaInsert));

                if (retcode != SQL_SUCCESS) {
                    printf("SQLPrepare: executeSqlStatement failed\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    //Si no hay ningún error ejecuto el SQL
                    retcode = SQLExecute(sqlstatementhandle);
                    if (!((retcode == SQL_SUCCESS) || (retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)))                  {
                        printf("return value: %d\n", retcode);
                        printf("SQLExecute: executeSqlStatement failed\n");
                    }
                }

                SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlstatementhandle);
                cout << "rc" << retcode << endl;
            }
            else {
                //No hacemos nada
            }
```

Actualizado, apliqué el consejo de @eferion declarando la cadena del insert como wstring pero me sigue dando el mismo fallo además me da error del paso de la cadena como segundo parámetro de SQLPrepare aunque le hice un cast a SQLWCHAR* y no sale este último.

```
//Hacemos la conversión a wstring de las variables
            wnombre = wstring(nombre.begin(), nombre.end());
            wdescripcion = wstring(descripcion.begin(), descripcion.end());
            
            if (resp == 's') {
                //Defino la cadena de conexión con la BD
                cadenaInsert = L"INSERT INTO Productos (nombre, descripcion, stock, precio) VALUES ('" + wnombre + "', '" + wdescripcion + "', '" + to_wstring(stock) + "', '" + to_wstring(precio) + "')";
                wcout << "Ejecutando: " << cadenaInsert << endl;
                //Libero cualquier resultado pendiente de la BD para ejecutar las siguientes instrucciones
                retcode = SQLFreeStmt(sqlstatementhandle, SQL_CLOSE);
                //Preparo la cadena SQL para su ejecución
                retcode = SQLPrepare(sqlstatementhandle, (SQLWCHAR*) cadenaInsert.c_str(), cadenaInsert.length());

                if (retcode != SQL_SUCCESS) {
                    printf("SQLPrepare: executeSqlStatement failed\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    //Si no hay ningún error ejecuto el SQL
                    retcode = SQLExecute(sqlstatementhandle);
                    if (!((retcode == SQL_SUCCESS) || (retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)))                  {
                        printf("return value: %d\n", retcode);
                        SQLGetDiagRec(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlstatementhandle, 1, sqlstate, NULL, message, 1024, NULL);
                        printf("SQLExecute: executeSqlStatement failed\n");
                    }
                }

                SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlstatementhandle);
                cout << "rc" << retcode << endl;
            }
            else {
                //No hacemos nada
            }
```

NOTA: Declaré al principio del método la cadena como wstring

[image: El mismo fallo me da]
El mismo fallo me sigue dando

Comment: El mayor problema es que no estás parametrizando tu consulta y la dejas abierta a inyección de SQL. Ese es uno de los mayores problemas de seguridad que existen y también uno muy sencillo de solucionar. Aquí hay un ejemplo de como hacerlo: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/cpp/data/oledb/issuing-a-parameterized-query?view=msvc-170

Comment: @LuisCazares gracias le echaré un ojo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error se produce porque, efectivamente, no existe ninguna sobrecarga del operador que haga lo que tu pretendes, y tiene sentido.

Tu estás intentando sumarle un `wstring` a un `wchar_t[]`, obteniendo como resultado un `wchar_t[]`, y esto no funciona por varias razones:

- Los arrays en C++ tienen que tener un tamaño conocido en tiempo de compilación. En este caso el tamaño final del array únicamente se conocería en tiempo de ejecución
- El array lo estás creando en la pila del programa. Es decir, aquí no podrías usar memoria dinámica.
- El operador suma genera un objeto temporal. Dado que no se puede utilizar memoria dinámica, no se pueden copiar punteros ¿Cómo copiamos entonces el contenido de ese objeto temporal en la pila? ¿Qué hacemos con el objeto temporal? ¿Se pierde su memoria?

No obstante no está todo perdido. Quizá la más sencilla sea crear un `wstring`:

```
std::wstring query = std::wstring(L"INSERT INTO Productos (nombre, descripcion, stock, precio) VALUES ('") + wnombre + L"', '" + wdescripcion + L"', '" + to_wstring(stock) + L"', '" + to_wstring(precio) + L"')";

wcout << "Ejecutando: " << query << endl;

retcode = SQLPrepare(sqlstatementhandle, query.c_str(), query.length());
```

---

**EDICIÓN**

Había dos problemas adicionales en el código:

1. El primer elemento no puede ser de tipo `wchar_t[]`, debe ser de tipo `std::wstring` (Por lo que he comentado antes del operador suma)
2. Todos los strings deben tener la `L` delante, un `char[]` no se puede convertir implícitamente en `wchar_t[]`

Comment: Vale, acabo de actualizar la pregunta con lo que me has recomendado

Comment: Me sigue sin ir... alguien me podría ayudar?

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ahora sí que me acaba de ir aunque me salió otro error relacionado con la SQL al ejecutar la consulta algo raro pero este lo pondré en otro hilo que ya es otro tema, saludos